# Bash sed delete a line from cron

Tags: bash, sed

Does anyone see anything wrong with the syntax here?

```
CTMPESC=$(sed 's/[\*\.&]/\\&/g' <<<"$CTMP")
crontab -l | sed "/$CTMPESC/d" | crontab -
```

CTMP is equal to a simple cron statement like so:

```
*/8 * * * * cd /home/administrator/anm-1.5.0 && ./anm.sh
```

I keep getting the error message:

sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown command: `8'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is that one of the slashes in `CTMPESC` closes the pattern, and whatever comes after it is interpreted as a command. You need to escape the slashes, too.

Add `/` to the class of characters you escape:

```
CTMPESC=$(sed 's/[\*\.&/]/\\&/g' <<<"$CTMP")
```

Comment: ...or they could do the deletion in a way that doesn't accept regexes, and so doesn't require any escaping at all, which would be more sensible. Think about `grep -F -v`, for instance.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy True. But this question is one of a bunch, where the OP does replacements on crontabs, too (using sed). Anyway, it's a very sound comment.

Comment: Excellent point Charles! Lev got me focused on sed in a previous issue for this exact same script and I completely forgot about the simple solutions. Worked great both of these, but ultimately went with the grep solution. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this in a way that leverages bash capabilities, there's no need for external tools such as grep or sed at all:

```
ctmp_content=$(<"$ctmp")
crontab -l | while read -r; do
  [[ $REPLY = *"$ctmp_content"* ]] && continue
  printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"
done | crontab -
```

Comment: Should 
`[[ $REPLY = *"$ctmp_content"* ]]`
not be 
`[[ "$REPLY" == *"$ctmp_content"* ]]`
?

Comment: @DaleA, either is valid for bash (and particularly for `[[ ]]`), but I prefer `=` because `=` is the only legal string comparison syntax inside POSIX test; getting folks in the habit of using it prevents them from writing `[ "$foo" == "$bar" ]` and being surprised when pure POSIX systems don't execute their scripts correctly.

Comment: @DaleA, ...see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html